# Priority-Web-SDK: Filtering a form

Tags: javascript, erp, priority-web-sdk

I am trying to understand how to use the [setSearchFilter](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setSearchFilter) function in the Priority Web SDK.  I can run formStart() followed by form.getRows(1) to get the entire form, but I only need ~5 of the over 100 rows.

```
login(configuration)
    .then(() => formStart('ORDERS', null, null, 'demo',1))
    .then(form => form.setSearchFilter({
        or: 0,
        ignorecase: 1,
        QueryValues: [{
            field: 'TOTPRICE',
            fromval: '100',
            op: '>'
        }]
    }))
    .then(filter => filter.getRows(1))
    .then(rows => console.log(rows))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

If I comment out the `then-setSearchFilter` line, I get the entire form.  With it in, I get `filter` undefined.

This is for a phone app so how much data I download seems important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation [setSearchFilter](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#setSearchFilter) doesn't return a filter object. After defining the filter each call to [getRows](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows) will return rows according to the filter. You should call it like this: `form.getRows` not `filter.getRows`.

In addition, when defining a [Filter](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#Filter) you must define all of its members.